# How do I make my button save results?

Tags: vb.net

I've been playing around learning the ropes of VB.NET.   I have started making my own small generator which just generates txt on the left hand side listbox based on whatever the user chooses in the combo box as you can see in the picture.   I would like to configure the already Save Results to open a file dialog box and allow the user to say what is already in the listbox in a txt file in any directory he or she choose.   Please look at my VB Program picture below to get a better understanding

[My VB program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmScj.png)

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 60 'change this to incrase green bar'
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    ' declare the required variables
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim item As String
    Dim fileReader As StreamReader

    ' set the value min and max values of progress bar


    ' clear the contents of the ListBox1
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    ' check whether an item is selected in the combox1
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        ' is selected get the item
        item = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Else
        ' otherwise set item to empty
        item = ""
    End If

    ' depending on the item initialize the fileReader with
    ' with respective file name


    If item.Equals("Random") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("world mix.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("China") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("china.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("Korea") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("korea.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("United Arab Emirates") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("ae.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("Russia") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("ru.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("USA") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("usa lead.txt")
    ElseIf item.Equals("New Zeland") Then
        fileReader = New StreamReader("nz.txt")
    Else
        fileReader = New StreamReader("names.txt")
    End If

    ' loop till end of the file
    Do While fileReader.Peek() <> -1

        ' check whether the progress is less than 200
        ' if so just increment the progress bar value
        If ProgressBar1.Value <= 100 Then
            ' set the line that is read into the listBox
            ListBox1.Items.Add(fileReader.ReadLine().ToString())

            ' increment the iterator


        End If
    Loop

    ' close the file
    fileReader.Close()



End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' when stop button is clicked, just display a pop up message
    MessageBox.Show("The progress bar has stopped!")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ''This is the save results button button''
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: [**SaveFileDialog tutorial**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_savefile_dialog.htm).